# How to avoid circular reference in database design

Tags: database, database-design

Given a Project with tasks, I have to know which task is active. A project can have many tasks. Only a task is active for each project.

Usually you need to show all tasks for a project but also the current task.

How would you model this in a database avoiding circular references?

**Update**

Other possible operations:

- add task
- remove task
- move to next task(making that one active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only have one task that is the active task for each project, I would add an attribute to the project table that has the identifier of that active task in it.

So the table PROJECT has attributes of (PROJECT_ID, NAME, ACTIVE_TASK_ID, etc), and the TASK table has (TASK_ID, NAME, PROJECT_ID).

This model allows you to have only zero or one active tasks in the project. Solutions that involve marking a particular task with a flag to indicate that it is active are not very easy to enforce integrity on.

Comment: Oh doh, I left the project ID off of the task table -- my bad.

Comment: Now a project can have a active_task that is connected to a different project.

Comment: I accept that it's a logical possibility based on the bare data model, but it can be prevented easily enough.  A trigger would probably be appropriate, although I'm not always a fan of that. Even the front-end could enforce it, as it is not the sort of intra-row integrity constraint that often causes problems.

Comment: @PeterRader Sure, it's conceptually possible. But that sort of statement is true any time you have a foreign key: it's always conceptually possible that it's pointing to a record that is invalid for any number of reasons. A rational program would never give the user the choice to select a task from a different project, so the only way it should be possible is if there's a bug in the data entry screens.

Comment: 1. The OP asked for a pure Database solution. 2. A database contains the base for calculations, not the result of calculations. 3. The responsibility of database is not only pure data: abstractions (like calculations of project's one-and-only-active-task) have their place in Databases. 4. A bug is an logical program-fault that can be solved, multiple active-tasks for a project are the `Object-relational-impendance mismatch` that maybe can not be solved. 5. A database's design is ACID - here you break the `Consistency`. 6. Six is a cool number.

Comment: @David this is my current model, but the client code that uses this db model tends to be hard to maintain. To many places that need to trigger the update on project. So I'm checking to see if there is better option.

Comment: Sometimes the better solution is defined just as much by your application technology, @danip. If your application technology makes it hard to implement a particular design, then I'd look for acceptable design alternatives in the database that achieve the same end goal. This model is easy to enforce consistency on in Ruby on Rails -- arguably it's easier than it is in the database itself, where enforcing rules such as "there shall be only one row per unique value of project_id that can have a value of 'true'" usually requires something slightly unnatural like a unique ... TBC

Comment: CONT ... function-based index. Workable, but a slight abomination. Triggers can be used to enforce this model, but again they're a slight abomination. So enforcement of either model at the RDBMS layer is possible, if a little unwieldy. I'd advise that you choose the model that works best with your application technology, and allows you as far as possible to define this functionality in a way that is robust and maintainable.

Comment: @PeterRader 1. Well, I don't think so. 2. Rather debatable 3. Contradicts (2) actually. 4. Don't follow why this is an issue of object-relational impedance -- no application technology type is mentioned at all. 5. Commercial RDBMSs are a flawed implementation of the relational database concept, and their capabilities in respect of enforcing data consistency are extremely primitive. Sometimes an application is better at it, particularly in inter-table relational integrity.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I accept that "hard to maintain" is no argument. Anyway: 1. The question is tagged by database and database-design only, he did not gave informations about design (mvc? just a wild guess). 2. Everything is debatable, is no argument. 3. Maybe! Actually everything is calculated ... time in example is calculated by the stength of gravitation and the distance to black-holes. Do you mean this? 4. I meat object-relational-impendance-*mismatch*, not a bug but a problem 5. i absolutly agree in this, it was a wild guess of mine that the database he meant follow ACID.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by  adding an "active" boolean field to table Task and use a constraint to ensure that only one such task exists for each project.

Answer (score 0):

One table with projects, one table with tasks, one table linking the two by id with a flag for active that has a constraint.

Comment: If only one task can be active at a time, I'd put an "active task id" field in the project rather than have an active flag. That way it's not logically possible to have two active tasks, and we can find the active task with one read instead of having to search.

Comment: Oh, I see that's exactly what David Aldridge said in his answer. Should have read all answers before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this scrawl

```
Table Project
   project_id PK
   name (String)
end;

Table Task
   task_id PK
   project_id FK
   active (Boolean)
-- Unique one Key to combination of "project_id" and "active=true".
end;
```

Comment: What do you think of the client code that will use this solution? First an update will be made to put the active task on false then another one to activate the new task.

Comment: If this updates are made in one single transaction you can set the constraint to be `deferrable` in SQL. If you start the transaction you need to set the transaction's constraint-check to "all deferred". This way the switch of the active task is made inside a single transaction until a savepoint or commit is reached. Actually inside the transaction you REALY have a short period of non active tasks for a project, but if you use pessimistic locking no other transaction or select would ever select this illegal state. Are you allowed to post the Database-Server-Type?

Comment: Sorry i meant `read committed only` not `pessimistic-locking`.